# Instantiate view controller created in storyboard from a storyboard less view controller

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have two View Controllers:

1. `MainController.swift` - Soryboard less view controller
2. `SecondController.swift` -  Storyboard view controller

How can I instantiate `SecondController` in `MainController`?

`storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: _)` does not work because MainController has no storyboard.

Comment: without storyboard means your controller is XIB?

Comment: You can address any storyboard in the bundle programmatically with [`init(name:bundle:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboard/1616216-init)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I open SecondController in MainController?

It depends what “open” means. You can, for example, say

```
present(SecondController(), animated:true)
```

Or you might push it onto a navigation controller if there is one in the interface. That sort of thing, and similar, are quite standard. Storyboards are a relatively recent innovation; when I started programming iOS everything was done without them.

Answer (score -1):

Use [init(name:bundle:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboard/1616216-init):

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let secondVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondController") as! SecondController
```

If you want to see example usage in an app then take a look at [this file](https://github.com/parthv21/Speech-Drill/blob/master/Speech-Drill/Controller/SideNavigationController/SideNavigationController.swift#L50).

Comment: What is "Main"?

Comment: Name of the sotryboard file that contains the view controllers. Take a look at the project I linked.

Comment: "MainController.swift without storyboard"

Comment: I'm sorry, the VC named needs to be SecondController.